# If $m^2+n^2=40$, where $m<0<n$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. What's $(m+n)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $m^2+n^2=40$, where $m<0<n$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. What's
> $(m+n)^2$?

I'm trying to see if there's a better approach to mine so that I can generalize the problem.

By primality test, $m,n < \lfloor{\sqrt{40}\rfloor}=6$ so $|m|,|n| \in \{1,2...6\} \stackrel{m^2, n^2}{\rightarrow} \{1,4,...,36\}$

By observation $4+36=40 \implies (m+n)^2=(-2+6)^2=(-6+2)^2=16$

Comment: Note that your bound really tells you that $|m|,|n|\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: For more formal writing, you can write $|m|,|n|\leq \lfloor \sqrt{40}\rfloor=6$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function. Otherwise your solution is fine, just see $m<0$ as pointed out by other users.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is there a better way to find the solution rather than guessing and checking the sum?

Comment: Since $m^2+n^2$ is divisible by 4, both $m$ and $n$ must be even, so $m, n\in\{0,2,4,6\}$. Now you can see the answer pretty much by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Being $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ where $m\lt0\lt n$, we have $m^2+n^2=40\iff(|m|,n)=(\pm6,2),(\pm2,6)$ so $(m+n)^2=64 \text { and }16$.